# Any Idea how I can pull this local value and pass it into another function?

Tags: javascript, angular, amazon-web-services

Basically what I need to do is pull a data location of an object I've uploaded and bind it and pass it to a specific form input in angular. I can get the data and its location which is basically the url key that I need to pass on my input form(image input) which will get me an image.

Here is my code :

export class UploadService{

```
uploadFile(file) {
    const contentType = file.type ; 
    var keyLocation; 
    var gettingKey = gettingKey(); 

    // console.log(`The location of the Key Needed is  ${keyLocation}`); 

    const bucket = new S3(
          {
              accessKeyId: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
              secretAccessKey: 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
          }
      );
      const params = {
          Bucket: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
          Key: file.name,
          Body: file,
          ACL: 'public-read',
          ContentType: contentType
      };


      bucket.upload(params, function (err, data) {

          if (err) {
              console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
              return false;
          }
          console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
          console.log("This is the Location Key "+ data.Location);

          data.Location = keyLocation; 
          return true; 

      }); 
      keyLocation = this.theKey; 
    //   return keyLocation; 
      function getKey(){
          return keyLocation; 
      }




//for upload progress   
bucket.upload(params).on('httpUploadProgress', function (evt) {
          console.log(evt.loaded + ' of ' + evt.total + ' Bytes');
      }).send(function (err, data) {
          if (err) {
              console.log('There was an error uploading your file: ', err);
              return false;
          }
          console.log('Successfully uploaded file.', data);
          return true;
      });

}


getKeyLocation(){     
     //Code in here 
}
```

}

So the code above is basically my upload service page on Angular. Through it i upload an image file. Now I need to get the location of the returning object/data which i get through data.Location as seen above. Now obviously I can see the location url link via the console but now I'm trying to get that value and pass it into that "getKeyLocation()" method so I can call it in another component and pass the location value into my image input on my form.

The input on my form basically goes like this: "image_url: this.uploadService.getKeyLocation()". As you can see I need the getKeyLocation() to pull the data so I can pass it to image_url input on my other ts component. Any idea how I can pass that data.Location into that getKeyLocation() method so it can return it for me. Any input would be helpful, even ones that deviate from this particular way to do it but as long as it leads to passing the location to image_url input on my object.

Comment: I believe that you assign variables in the wrong order. I mean is you erase data.Location doing tihs `data.Location = keyLocation;` because keyLocation is undefined.
The whole thing here seams overcomplicated and I can't see see what you are trying to do.
Is it angular.js or angular 2+?
Btw. don't use var, use let.

Comment: I'm using Angularjs

Comment: You can store variables for services  not only for funtions in services.

Comment: Even if I store variables, how would i be able to pass this particular one(data.Location) somewhere else. Remember it's a local variable and I'm struggling to make it global. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: function someService {
  let varThatIWantToPass = null;
  firstFunction() {
    // get the var from somewhere
    varThatIWantToPass = varThatIJustGot;
  }

  secondFunction() {
    return varThatIWantToPass;
  }
}